# UNITY: How to implement thread safe Container.Resolve() function with constructor injection?

Tags: c#, unity-container, constructor-injection

I'm using Unity 2.0 in my project where I'm reading a lot of files at the same time inside Parallel.ForEach block of code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, currentFile =>
{
    using(IMsBuildProjectLoader msBuildProject = Container.Resolve<IMsBuildProjectLoader>(new ParameterOverride("projectFileName", currentFile)))
    {
        // file processing
    }
}
```

Resolve(new ParameterOverride("projectFileName", currentFile) function sometimes throw ResolutionFailedException:

```
ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, 
type = "Porthus.Build.Common.Interfaces.IMsBuildProjectLoader", name = "(none)". 
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor XXX.Build.Common.Types.MsBuildProjectLoader(System.String projectFileName). 
Exception is: ArgumentException - Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'xxx'  Key being added: 'xxx'
```

This is when the same file is loaded at the same time - Resolve function is creating two IMsBuildProjectLoader instances with the same parameter at the same time. It cannot be solved by files.Distinct() filter. Above code is only a code example to explain my problem.

**The question is**: How to implement thread safe UnityContainer.Resolve function? Is it possible to do it using some Unity extension class?

**IMsBuildProjectLoader**:

```
public interface IMsBuildProjectLoader : IDisposable
{
}
```

**MsBuildProjectLoader**:

```
public class MsBuildProjectLoader : Project, IMsBuildProjectLoader
{
    public MsBuildProjectLoader(string projectFileName)
        : base()
    {
        // Load the contents of the specified project file.
        Load(projectFileName);
    }
}
```

MsBuildProjectLoader is registered this way:

```
container.RegisterType<IMsBuildProjectLoader, MsBuildProjectLoader>();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think you might be doing it wrong. Your class should be injected with an IMsBuildProjectLoader, and in your loop, you should call a method on the IMsBuildProjectLoader that takes the file name as a parameter. The thread safety should then be baked into your implementation of the IMsBuildProjectLoader. My $0.02.

Comment: Yes, that's another option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolve is actually thread safe (or so say the guys at Microsoft P&P).
What is probably not thread safe is the implementation of *MsBuildProjectLoader*, or more specifically it's constructor.
You would probably stumble the same issue by simply creating new instances of MsBuildProjectLoader using *new* in the same asynchronous manner

You didn't include the implementation of Load, but according to the exception I would assume it manipulates a shared or static dictionary in a not thread-safe manner.
If this is the case, you should make that dictionary thread safe (for example by replacing it with a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).